# LAContext canEvaluatePolicy and Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is my code in Swift:

```
if (LAContext().canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)) {
  return true;
}
```

With Swift2 I changed my code to look like this:

```
if #available(iOS 8, *) {
            if (LAContext().canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
```

But I get the following error:

> Call can throw, but it is not marked with 'try' and the error is not handled

What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: The method can throw, you should have a look at the new error handling in Swift 2: http://www.hackingwithswift.com/new-syntax-swift-2-error-handling-try-catch

Comment: But why doesn't it returns BOOL anymore?

Comment: This is kind of confusing and is ambiguous at best. canEvaluatePolicy implies that the Bool return value could be false even if there is no error. But now the meaning appears to be that it can only be false if there is an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

```
do {
    try laContext.canEvaluatePolicy(.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)

    // Call evaluatePolicy here
} catch {
    print("Cannot evaluate policy, error: \(error)")
}
```

All methods that returned a `Bool` and had an `inout NSError?` as the last parameter were automatically converted (Swift 2) to throw the error, so the parameter was removed. Also the `Bool` was redundant because it was equal to whether the `inout NSError?` is nil

EDIT: To get more information about the error use this within the catch:

```
switch LAError(rawValue: error.code)! {
case .AuthenticationFailed:
    break
case .UserCancel:
    break
case .UserFallback:
    break
case .SystemCancel:
    break
case .PasscodeNotSet:
    break
case .TouchIDNotEnrolled:
    break
default:
    break
}
```

(You can look at all the possible errors by CMD clicking on `LAError`

EDIT: In XCode 7 beta 5/6 this method doesn't throw anymore, but takes an `NSErrorPointer` as the last parameter (as does `NSURL`'s `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` for reasons not known to me). You can however extend your `LAContext` to make a throwing method like before if you like:

```
extension LAContext {
    func canEvaluatePolicyThrowing(policy: LAPolicy) throws {
        var error : NSError?
        canEvaluatePolicy(policy, error: &error)
        if let error = error { throw error }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just openend an old project after a while, with the latest Xcode 7 beta 5, and the compiler is complaining about the missing `error` argument... The inline docs also list the method as `- canEvaluatePolicy:error:`... WHAT'S GOING ON???

Comment: @NicolasMiari Yeah I saw that too, same as `checkResourseIsReachable...` on `NSURL`

Comment: So, I should revert to `inout NSError` and throw away (no pun intended) my `do/try` block? I don't even remember how to declare the error variable at this point... let? var? NSError? NSErrorPointer? Can't keep up...

Comment: One more thing: error is defined as `NSError?`, so you need to change `switch LAError(rawValue: error.code)! ` into: `switch LAError(rawValue: error!.code)!` in your code (otherwise I get a compiler error).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
do {

        try touchIDContext.canEvaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics)


    //Comprobar la repuesta de esa autentificacion

    touchIDContext.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.DeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: mensaje, reply: { (success, ErrorType) -> Void in


            if success
            {
               // Autentificacion correcta
                alert.title = "Genial!"
                alert.message = "Te has autentificado correctamente"

                // Mostramos este Alerview

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

            else
            {
                //AUTENTIFICACION FALLIDA
                //PASAMOS VALORES AL ALERTVIEW
                alert.title = "AUTENTIFICACION FALLIDA!!"

                //OFRECEMOS MAS INFORMACION SOBRE EL FALLO DE AUTENTIFICAICON

                switch ErrorType!.code {

                case LAError.UserCancel.rawValue: alert.message = "Usuario Cancela"
                case LAError.AuthenticationFailed.rawValue: alert.message = "Autentificacion Fallida!"
                case LAError.PasscodeNotSet.rawValue: alert.message = "Password no configurado"
                case LAError.SystemCancel.rawValue: alert.message = "Error de sistema"
                case LAError.UserFallback.rawValue:alert.message = "Usuario selecciona contrasen"
                default:alert.message = "Imposible Autentificarse"

            }

                //Mostramos el AlertView

                self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }) // cierre del clousure





    } // cierre del do

    catch {

        print("Cannot evaluate policy, error: \(error)")
    } // cierre del catch
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3, I do this:

```
context.evaluatePolicy(policy, localizedReason: ...) { (success: Bool, error: Error?) in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if success {
            ...
        } else if let error = error as? LAError {
            switch error.code {
            case LAError.authenticationFailed:
            ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```